# Someone claiming to be from my phone provider called asking me to add money to my account. Is this a scam?

Tags: india, scams

Someone called me to ask whether I have recharged (added money to) my mobile account. He told me that he was calling from the network provider and wanted to assist me with the recharge. Unlike an automated call that I usually get, this was an actual person who was calling, and I had not even contacted their customer care or anything. This left me a bit suspicious and after checking the number later in a website, I found that there were a lot of people who reported that number to be scam.

However, I do not know how someone can scam people by knowing just their mobile phone account details. Is there any scam like this or am I just overreacting?

Comment: When you say "recharge", do you mean apply more money to your mobile phone payment account? (I would normally associate it with plugging in the phone to fill up the battery, but that can't be what you mean here). What details did you provide to the caller?

Comment: Best guess is that the almost-certain-scammer – in assisting you with the recharge – would have got you to give him your credit-/debit-card or bank details  Or they may have directed you to login to a fake website. Or given _you_ the details of another account to send "top-up" money to (owned by a different victim, but under their control).  _Recognising_ it's a scam is generally more important than worrying about the precise mechanics.

Comment: It's a straightforward scam.

Comment: @Vicky In South Asian and some Southeast Asian varieties of English, "recharge" means adding money to a phone payment account. "Recharge" may also be used interchangeably with "top-up".

Comment: As Tripe explains there are 3 or 4 ways the scam plays out, either via websites or card numbers.

Comment: (I would have thought that these days everyone knows what "recharge" can mean - much as it's absolutely no surprise about "boot ! / trunk!" on a car in different English-speaking regions.)

Comment: @Vicky Yes, I meant applying  more money, like top-up. And regarding what information I provided, I provided nothing other than whether I have already done payment or not. Maybe, I shouldn't have told that either, but I don't see what use it can be; and hence the question.

Comment: hi @DeepakMS (1) naturally, you should simply hang up  (2) you explain that the only thing you said was "whether or not you made a top up" - really you should be fine.  Of course next time just hang up! I was wondering, could you tell was it a scam team calling from the US, or just locally?

Comment: Good life hack - if you have to ask "Is this a scam?" It almost certainly is!

Comment: @Fattie >> that these days everyone knows - There are new people born all the time (about 256 per minute globally).  Consider the implications ...

Comment: Who was the person who came up with the original tenet "if you post it here, it's a scam"? :-)

Comment: If you use a credit or debit card, they will ask you for all the details normally used for payment over the phone, including those CVV digits on the back of the card. They will then turn around and call some over-the-phone seller and use the details you just gave to order something very expensive which they can then sell on to get cash.

Comment: @mcalex [There's an xkcd for that!](https://xkcd.com/1053/)

Comment: There is a reason many collections people will not call you to do this - rather, they will say "Call the support line on your latest bill to discuss an important matter."

Comment: I never give information to callers. Once they called me from the bank. They asked me for my national id number to confirm that it was really me who answered the phone. I told them that first they should prove their identity to me. Eventually, they read out my id number to me, except for the last two digits, which I added myself. With more sensitive information I would demand to call them back (to a number I'm familiar with or that I would get from an independent, reputable source).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you mean "recharge" as in add more money to your phone payment account, then this is 100% a scam. For the following reasons:

1. The phone provider will most likely not call you asking for personal details to apply a payment. *Even if* they did call to tell you a payment is due, it would either be an automated message that says "your payment is due" or they would call *and only have to verify the information they already have on file*.
2. This sounds exactly like scammers calling you and saying they are from "Microsoft" and want to help you renew your Windows subscription. Usually they make you buy some gift cards and send them the numbers.
3. You looked up the phone number and many people have reported it as spam/scam.

If you want to be sure your phone account is in good standing, look for the main customer service number online and speak to them. *Do not* call back the number that called you originally.

EDIT: This is from my own experience in the USA. I don't know if providers directly calling customers is more common in India, where the OP is from.

Comment: OP is from Kerala, India. In South Asian varieties of English, "recharge" means adding money to a phone payment account.

Comment: it's 100% a straightforward, common, well-known scam (in India and elsewhere)

Answer (score 14):

For clarity, in case this helps someone:

- It's an **extremely well-known, very popular, scam** (in India and elsewhere).

It's totally common to get 3 or 4 calls with this particular scam each month.

Completely ignore it.

Comment: If OP was bored they could spend some time catfishing the caller, to irritate them and limit their call-rate.  I remember a co-worker spending a good **half-hour** convincing a scam-caller that he was a combined computer hardware reseller and laundromat and that his mother in law was recently fired from her position as sandwich board, and toward the end, that his name was Dong, first name, Long.   It was hillarious.